# Two arguments given but claims three arguments given

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
l2_penalty = np.logspace(1, 7, num=13)
plt.xscale('log',l2_penalty)
```

I got error message:

```
TypeError: set_xscale() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Why, I gave only two arguments?

Comment: Your stack trace doesn't match your code. `plt.xscale` vs `set_xscale`

Comment: what does `xscale` call?

Comment: It seems like your are calling some `xscale` function and some other is being called, it could be due to a scope issue, or may be you are showing some other code and running some other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call signature of `plt.xscale` is `xscale(*args, **kwargs)`, however in the documentation the call signature is actually `plt.xscale(scale, **kwargs)`.

When the function is called, all the unnamed arguments (passed in through `*args`) are passed onto another function internally.  Each of the unnamed arguments you have provided are then given to the other function expanded out, so (as an example):

```
def xscale(*args, *kwargs):
    # Do some stuff
    first_argument = 10

    # Call another function taking only 2 arguments
    other_function(first_argument, *args)
    # This expands to: other_function(first_argument, 'log',l2_penalty)
    # And since the target only takes 2 arguments and you provided 3
    # It is this internal call that causes an error.

    # Probably do some other stuff...
```

It's important to provide the full stack trace on SO when asking for help debugging these kinds of problems.  I had to run your code myself and I'm hoping that it produced the same error as yours, but I have no grantee...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1502, in xscale
    ax.set_xscale(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: set_xscale() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

If you want to pass in additional arguments to the `plt.xscale` function you will need to pass them in as named arguments and follow the documentation:

> ```
>     'log'
>
>         *basex*/*basey*:
>            The base of the logarithm
>
>         *nonposx*/*nonposy*: ['mask' | 'clip' ]
>           non-positive values in *x* or *y* can be masked as
>           invalid, or clipped to a very small positive number
>
>         *subsx*/*subsy*:
>            Where to place the subticks between each major tick.
>            Should be a sequence of integers.  For example, in a log10
>            scale: ``[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]``
>
>            will place 8 logarithmically spaced minor ticks between
>            each major tick.
> ```

The following examples might be useful using named arguments:

```
plt.xscale('log', basex=10, basey=5)
plt.xscale('log', subsx=[2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the `plot.xscale` docs.  It is a bound method, so one positional arg is `self`.  The other is a word like 'log'.  All other args require a keyword.'

`set_xscale` is an `axes` method that takes the same arguments.  The `plot` method probably delegates to the `axes` method.